# Concatenating two columns into one with dynamic range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate two columns in Excel using VBA. Everything before "Dim..." is just formatting I need for the sheet I'm working with. The "Dim..." piece is giving me trouble because it moves all of the result data up one row and eliminates the value I have in D2 to start. The code I am using is below:

```
Range("D1").EntireColumn.Insert

 Range("D1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "General"

 Range("D2").Select

Dim lngLastRow As Long 
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("D2:D" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(R[1]C[1],"""",R[1]C[2])"
```

**Raw data:**

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYAxU.png)

**Results:**

[Results after macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QB2b.png)

Any help would be awesome and if you need anything else, let me know! I tried to include all pertinent info.

Comment: Aren't you concatenating offset rows? Try: Range("D2:D" & lngLastRow).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(R[0]C[1],"""",R[0]C[2])"

Comment: @Flephal I concur as long as that header is in your file as well.

Comment: @Flephal That worked!